# Average of each day over multiple years

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Quick Q:

Have a dataset: That is a measurment per day over several years. 
Trying to work out the average of all the same dates. i.e the average of 01/01/1995 and 01/01/1996 and 01/01/1997 etc.

Tried this:

```
z=df.groupby(df.index.day,df.index.month).mean()
```

But get:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Cheers

Comment: how is your data stored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC you need to pass a list:

```
z=df.groupby([df.index.day,df.index.month]).mean()
```

What you did was pass multiple args so it interpreted the months array as an arg for `axis`, see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby)

Comment: Thats great
Just to check, will this (as I have split it up as for several year periods i.e from 1990-2000 and 2000-2010) keep them in the same order.

Just the labels atm say (1,1), (2,20), (4,11),(5,31),(7,20),(9,8),(10,28),(12,17)

Comment: It will order them by the list of args you pass unless you want to retain the df order, in which case pass `sort=False`

Comment: A note: reversing the syntax gives a result that is more intuitive; first index is month, second is day. `dat.groupby([dat.index.month, dat.index.day]).mean()`. Otherwise, you might be scratching your head about why there are only 12 days in your month for a minute before realizing what is going on.

Comment: @EHB I live in a part of the world where the convention is `dd/mm/yyyy` how dates are represented is a matter of local preferences, additionally this is the format that the OP requested

Answer (score 1):

Hey @EdChum just adding this as an answer, as the display of the comment doesn't let me show what I meant. I agree that date format is a superior syntax! However, when I do it in reverse order I get

```
    WindSpeed

1   1   1   9.283333
1   2   6.694444
1   3   7.861111
1   4   9.223529
...
1   31  8.964706
2   1   9.127778
2   2   8.733333
2   3   7.511111
...
```

Where the first index is month, and the second is day.
When I do in the order you suggested, I get:

```
    WindSpeed
1   1   9.283333
1   2   8.361111
1   3   6.670588
1   4   7.155556
1   5   8.450000
1   6   4.777778
1   7   3.666667
1   8   4.011765
1   9   5.210526
1   10  6.972222
1   11  7.647059
1   12  6.844444
...
```

Where the first index is day (from 1-31), and the second is month (from 1-12). We usually look at data sequentially, with January 1 followed by Jan 2. In yours, January first is followed by February first. That confused me for a bit! Mine worked better for my needs anyways. I appreciated your answer here a lot! Helped me with my problem.